# JSON.parse unexpected token s at position 0

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to learn about JSON and watching a Udemy video. During the code along I get the JSON.parse unexpected token s at position 0. I'm not quite sure how to fix the error or what it entails entirely.

I've checked out the Q&A section of the video and it seems like a lot of people are running into the same error but no solution is working. I've also checked out some of the stackoverflow answers, but I'm so new to the concept of JSON that it makes zero sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const express = require("express");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const request = require("request"); // use to do a request to an external 
server

const app = express();



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));



 app.get("/", function(req, res) {

 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");

 });



app.post("/", function(req, res) {



 var crypto = req.body.crypto;

 var fiat = req.body.fiat;



 var URL = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/";

 var finalURL = URL + crypto + fiat;

 request(finalURL, function(error, response, body) {



var data = JSON.parse(body)

var price = data.last;

var currentDate = data.display_timestamp;



res.write("The current date is " + currentDate);

res.write("<h1>The current price of" +  crypto + " is: " + price + fiat + 
"</h1>");

res.send();

});

});

app.listen(3000, function() {

console.log("Server started on port 3000.");



});
```

HTML Part

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <select name=" crypto">
    <option value="BTC">Bitcoin</option>
    <option value="ETH">Ethereum</option>
    <option value="LTC">Lightcoin</option>
    </select>

    <select name="fiat">
      <option value="USD">US Dollars</option>
      <option value="GBP">GB Pounds</option>
      <option value="EUR">EU Euros</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" name="button">Check</button>
</form>
```

The expected output should be when you select the crypto currency and curreny (like $, pounds , euros) it will tell you what the price of the crypto currency is.

Comment: What are you getting for `body`?

Comment: `request(finalURL, function(error, response, body) { console.log(body)`

Comment: You can remove the extra space before `crypto` in your HTML. If that was it, you can delete this question.

Comment: Due to the space in `<select name=" crypto">` you added `UNDEFINEDUSD` to the url instead of for instance `BTCUSD`. The API replies with text: `Symbol UNDEFINEDUSD is not supported. etc` Since you're trying to parse this but it's not JSON, you receive the error. Note that most of this can easily be determined by looking at the command prompt where you started the app; node spells out the API reply right before complaining about the unexpected token. And add `res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset:utf-8");` to the reply code before sending it.

Comment: The most important lesson here is to learn to love `console.log()` which allows you to check all variables at any time to make sure they contain what you think they contain. Finally, the concept of JSON is sending text like this: https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCEUR which can be parsed into an Object. Firefox even pre-parses it and shows the result as tree.

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone who posted! Was able to get the code working! Shout out to @ChrisG. It was the added space in the HTML that was throwing off the whole code!

Answer (score 0):

When making a request with the wrong URL to this API, you get a string back which results into JSON.parse returning this error. it could be that the API provider changed this link overtime. Try visiting this api route in your browser and see if it works.

Most likely you're passing the wrong URL.